# How to Get the VM Budget in Android for Bitmaps?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, out-of-memory

Is there some way to find the VM budget for bitmaps?

My app displays two photographs at once and this is possible given appropriate scaling and colour depth, but, if the device has a bigger VM budget (as some do), I would like the app to use it for better image quality.  Is there an API call to get the VM budget?

I have done this using binary trial and error but it is slow.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ActivityManager.getMemoryClass()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29) to get the amount of memory allowed per process, then deduct the estimated maximum amount of memory your code needs, the rest can be used for displaying your images.

Comment: Thanks Kai, I am trying it now.

Comment: Thanks Kai, It gives 64 on my phone.  As far as I can tell, the 64mbyte budget includes all memory that my app uses including bitmaps.

Comment: Yes it does, so you have to calculate the budget for graphics/Bitmaps yourself. Also note that on old/low-end phones the value may only be 16MB or 24MB, and on pre Android 3.0 devices it takes some time for the OS to release graphics related memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try Runtime class.

```
Runtime rt = getRuntime();
rt.totalMemory(); //Returns the total amount of memory which is available to the running program.
```

refer to http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html

Comment: Thanks yushulx, This gives 5,509,104 on my phone, which corresponds to one of the amounts reported in the LogCat.  I did more investigating on "Runtime" and found rt.maxMemory() to return 67,108,864 which means 64mbytes.